# Do living things have a magnetic field capable of any level of solar protection?

Tags: geophysics, geochemistry, geomagnetism, biogeochemistry, electromagnetism

I understand how anything with an electrical current have a magnetic field including living things. Would a densely populated rain forest or jungle have enough combined magnetic field among the living things in a area have any level of protection from solar radiation compared to seperate?

Comment: @Gimelist here.